# How to reset WP plugin?

Tags: plugins, cache

I installed a plugin a few days back and deleted it. When I installed it again, it is showing the same data entries which I previously entered in the plugin. I have cached all the data but the problem still persist.

Can anyone help me out in solving this issue where the plugin show no previous data entries, just a newly installed plugin?

The plugin is WP nearby places.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE, perhaps you take first a look at the help page(s) of the developer(s) and ask for help at their forum. Because supporting a 3rd party plugin is not the goal of WPSE, but that is also standing in the [tour guide.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: There is no way to reset a plugin configuration with the core wordpress functionalities, it's up to the plugin to provide that option.